# Simple, small C program for testing serial bandwidth

Tags: c, serial-port, embedded-linux

I have two laptops with a serial port.  How do I test the actual bandwidth of the serial port between the two machines using a simple, small C program?

In reality, I need to do this on an embedded Linux system which is why the utility must be a small, simple C program (because the embedded environment only has limited library support meaning it doesn't have python, perl, or any other fancy libraries).

Comment: Very broad question that borders on "Write this program for me, please."  I don't know anything about Linux serial ports but I'd begin by finding out how to open a port and send "hello world" to the other machine and have it reply back.  Once you can do that, measuring bandwidth is easy.

Comment: You could use eg sz (simple, short program to send files serially using xmodem, ymodem or zmodem).  Should be easy to port over to the embedded machine.  Once you have ported it just send a file across and look at the transfer speed sz indicates.  At the very least the program can serve as an inspiration wrt how to work with serial data, display diagnostic info regularly, etc.

Comment: If it's a serial port, your bandwidth is going to be pretty well defined by your port speed.  If you're community at, say, 57600 bps...that's your bandwidth, right there.  Your *effective* bandwidth may be lower if you've got some sort of protocol framing going on, but it sounds like you don't from your question.

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast!  I have 3 responses in the time that I was answering my own question.  In reality I posted this with the answer already in hand (maybe I should note that in the question next time...) and just wanted to share my solution with everybody else.  I don't personally take the time to answer other peoples questions, so I thought I could alternatively give back to the community by posting both the Q and A of daily tech problems that I solve.

Comment: @BradGrissom: I think when you ask a question there's a little checkbox that lets you answer it at the same time. If you post both at the same time then people will know you're answering your own question since, well, you already did by the time anyone sees it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started this as a new question because I didn't want to take this question off topic: [Serial port loopback test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701955/serial-port-loopback-duplex-test-in-bash-or-c-process-substitution)

That question was regarding testing the bandwidth of a serial port in loopback mode, so that you don't have to plug in an actual serial cable.  The author (sdaau) put *a lot* of time into creating a multi-threaded serial bandwidth test program to answer his own question.  I then used his simple C program and extended it to be used between two different physical machines connected with a serial cable.

It is necessary to start the "remote" side which will wait for the "initiator" side (the local side) to send a go byte, in which both will proceed to transfer data asynchronously.  The program (which sdaau calls writeread.c) spawns 2 threads: one which writes data and the other which reads data.  In this way, you are fully utilizing the serial port.  You can pass in a datafile as a command-line argument.

As an example, here is the "remote" side:

```
./writeread /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 ./datafile.dat 3> output
```

As an example, here is the "local" (or initiator) side:

```
./writeread /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 ./datafile.dat -I 3> output
```

Note that I had some trouble redirecting the output on the remote side, meaning that `3> output` didn't really work.  I'm not sure whats going on with that, but my local side worked fine.  Also, note the remote side's output timing is skewed because it has a timer running while it is waiting for the initiator.  This means you should only trust the bandwidth printout from the local initiator side (see the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701955/serial-port-loopback-duplex-test-in-bash-or-c-process-substitution) question for output results details).

Since both sides are sending the same datafile in this example, you should be able to compare the "output" file with the datafile:

```
diff output datafile.dat
```

Complie the code with:

```
gcc -c -Wall writeread.c
gcc writeread.o -lpthread -o writeread
```

Here is the modified writeread.c code:

```
/*
    writeread.c - based on writeread.cpp
    [SOLVED] Serial Programming, Write-Read Issue - http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/serial-programming-write-read-issue-822980/

    build with: gcc -o writeread -lpthread -Wall -g writeread.c
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <pthread.h>

#include "writeread.h"


int serport_fd;

//POSIX Threads Programming - https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#PassingArguments
struct write_thread_data{
   int  fd;
   char* comm; //string to send
   int bytesToSend;
   int writtenBytes;
   int iator; // Initiator.  0 = False, 1 = True
};

void usage(char **argv)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "Usage:\n"); 
    fprintf(stdout, "%s port baudrate file/string [-I]\n", argv[0]); 
    fprintf(stdout, "   The -I is for initiator.  Run on the remote side which "
                    "will wait, then start locally with -I which will initiate "
                    "the test.\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "Examples:\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "%s /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 /path/to/somefile.txt\n", argv[0]); 
    fprintf(stdout, "%s /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 \"some text test\"\n", argv[0]); 
}

// POSIX threads explained - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-posix1.html
// instead of writeport
void *write_thread_function(void *arg) {
    int go = 0;
    int lastBytesWritten;
    struct write_thread_data *my_data;
    my_data = (struct write_thread_data *) arg;

    fprintf(stdout, "write_thread_function spawned\n");

    // Are we the initiator?
    if (my_data->iator == 1) {
        // We are the initiator, send the start command
        go = 0xde;
        write(my_data->fd, &go, 1);
    } else {
        // We wait for the initiator to send us the start command
        fprintf(stdout, "Waiting for initiator (start other end with -I)...\n");
        read(my_data->fd, &go, 1);
        if (go == 0xde) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Go!\n");
        } else {
            fprintf(stdout, "Error: Did not receive start command [0x%x]\n", go);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    my_data->writtenBytes = 0; 
    while(my_data->writtenBytes < my_data->bytesToSend)
    {
        lastBytesWritten = write( my_data->fd, my_data->comm + my_data->writtenBytes, my_data->bytesToSend - my_data->writtenBytes );   
        my_data->writtenBytes += lastBytesWritten;  
        if ( lastBytesWritten < 0 ) 
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "write failed!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "   write: %d - %d\n", lastBytesWritten, my_data->writtenBytes);
    }
    return NULL; //pthread_exit(NULL)
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ) 
{

    if( argc < 4 ) { 
        usage(argv);
        return 1; 
    }

    char *serport;
    char *serspeed;
    speed_t serspeed_t;
    char *serfstr;
    int serf_fd; // if < 0, then serfstr is a string
    int sentBytes; 
    int readChars;
    int recdBytes, totlBytes; 

    char* sResp;
    char* sRespTotal;

    struct timeval timeStart, timeEnd, timeDelta;
    float deltasec, expectBps, measReadBps, measWriteBps; 

    struct write_thread_data wrdata;
    pthread_t myWriteThread;

    /* Re: connecting alternative output stream to terminal - 
    * http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2009-01/msg01616.html 
    * send read output to file descriptor 3 if open, 
    * else just send to stdout
    */
    FILE *stdalt;
    if(dup2(3, 3) == -1) {
        fprintf(stdout, "stdalt not opened; ");
        stdalt = fopen("/dev/tty", "w");
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "stdalt opened; ");
        stdalt = fdopen(3, "w");
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Alternative file descriptor: %d\n", fileno(stdalt));

    // Get the PORT name
    serport = argv[1];
    fprintf(stdout, "Opening port %s;\n", serport);

    // Get the baudrate
    serspeed = argv[2];
    serspeed_t = string_to_baud(serspeed);
    fprintf(stdout, "Got speed %s (%d/0x%x);\n", serspeed, serspeed_t, serspeed_t);

    //Get file or command;
    serfstr = argv[3];

    // Are we the initiator?
    if (argc == 5 &&
        strncmp(argv[4], "-I", 3) == 0 )
    {
        wrdata.iator = 1; // Initiator.  0 = False, 1 = True
    } else {
        wrdata.iator = 0; // Initiator.  0 = False, 1 = True
    }

    serf_fd = open( serfstr, O_RDONLY );
    fprintf(stdout, "Got file/string '%s'; ", serfstr);
    if (serf_fd < 0) {
        wrdata.bytesToSend = strlen(serfstr);
        wrdata.comm = serfstr; //pointer already defined 
        fprintf(stdout, "interpreting as string (%d).\n", wrdata.bytesToSend);
    } else {
        struct stat st;
        stat(serfstr, &st);
        wrdata.bytesToSend = st.st_size;
        wrdata.comm = (char *)calloc(wrdata.bytesToSend, sizeof(char));
        read(serf_fd, wrdata.comm, wrdata.bytesToSend);
        fprintf(stdout, "opened as file (%d).\n", wrdata.bytesToSend);
    }

    sResp = (char *)calloc(wrdata.bytesToSend, sizeof(char));
    sRespTotal = (char *)calloc(wrdata.bytesToSend, sizeof(char));

    // Open and Initialise port
    serport_fd = open( serport, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK );
    if ( serport_fd < 0 ) { perror(serport); return 1; }
    initport( serport_fd, serspeed_t );

    wrdata.fd = serport_fd;

    sentBytes = 0; recdBytes = 0;

    gettimeofday( &timeStart, NULL );

    // start the thread for writing.. 
    if ( pthread_create( &myWriteThread, NULL, write_thread_function, (void *) &wrdata) ) {
        printf("error creating thread.");
        abort();
    }

    // run read loop 
    while ( recdBytes < wrdata.bytesToSend )
    {

        while ( wait_flag == TRUE );

        if ( (readChars = read( serport_fd, sResp, wrdata.bytesToSend)) >= 0 ) 
        {
            //~ fprintf(stdout, "InVAL: (%d) %s\n", readChars, sResp);
            // binary safe - add sResp chunk to sRespTotal
            memmove(sRespTotal+recdBytes, sResp+0, readChars*sizeof(char));
            /* // text safe, but not binary:
            sResp[readChars] = '\0'; 
            fprintf(stdalt, "%s", sResp);
            */
            recdBytes += readChars;
        } else {
            if ( errno == EAGAIN ) 
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "SERIAL EAGAIN ERROR\n");
                return 0;
            } 
            else 
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "SERIAL read error: %d = %s\n", errno , strerror(errno));
                return 0;
            }           
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "   read: %d\n", recdBytes);        

        wait_flag = TRUE; // was ==
        //~ usleep(50000);
    }

    if ( pthread_join ( myWriteThread, NULL ) ) {
        printf("error joining thread.");
        abort();
    }

    gettimeofday( &timeEnd, NULL );

    // binary safe - dump sRespTotal to stdalt
    fwrite(sRespTotal, sizeof(char), recdBytes, stdalt);

    // Close the open port
    close( serport_fd );
    if (!(serf_fd < 0)) { 
        close( serf_fd );
        free(wrdata.comm); 
    } 
    free(sResp);
    free(sRespTotal);

    fprintf(stdout, "\n+++DONE+++\n");

    sentBytes = wrdata.writtenBytes; 
    totlBytes = sentBytes + recdBytes;
    timeval_subtract(&timeDelta, &timeEnd, &timeStart);
    deltasec = timeDelta.tv_sec+timeDelta.tv_usec*1e-6;
    expectBps = atoi(serspeed)/10.0f; 
    measWriteBps = sentBytes/deltasec;
    measReadBps = recdBytes/deltasec;

    fprintf(stdout, "Wrote: %d bytes; Read: %d bytes; Total: %d bytes. \n", sentBytes, recdBytes, totlBytes);
    fprintf(stdout, "Start: %ld s %ld us; End: %ld s %ld us; Delta: %ld s %ld us. \n", timeStart.tv_sec, timeStart.tv_usec, timeEnd.tv_sec, timeEnd.tv_usec, timeDelta.tv_sec, timeDelta.tv_usec);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s baud for 8N1 is %d Bps (bytes/sec).\n", serspeed, (int)expectBps);
    fprintf(stdout, "Measured: write %.02f Bps (%.02f%%), read %.02f Bps (%.02f%%), total %.02f Bps.\n", measWriteBps, (measWriteBps/expectBps)*100, measReadBps, (measReadBps/expectBps)*100, totlBytes/deltasec);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the .h file which I have renamed from the original question to writeread.h:

```
/* writeread.h
    (C) 2004-5 Captain http://www.captain.at

    Helper functions for "ser"

    Used for testing the PIC-MMC test-board
    http://www.captain.at/electronic-index.php
*/

#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

int wait_flag = TRUE;   // TRUE while no signal received

// Definition of Signal Handler
void DAQ_signal_handler_IO ( int status )
{
    //~ fprintf(stdout, "received SIGIO signal %d.\n", status);
    wait_flag = FALSE;
}


int writeport( int fd, char *comm ) 
{
    int len = strlen( comm );
    int n = write( fd, comm, len );

    if ( n < 0 ) 
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "write failed!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    return n;
}


int readport( int fd, char *resp, size_t nbyte ) 
{
    int iIn = read( fd, resp, nbyte );
    if ( iIn < 0 ) 
    {
        if ( errno == EAGAIN ) 
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "SERIAL EAGAIN ERROR\n");
            return 0;
        } 
        else 
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "SERIAL read error: %d = %s\n", errno , strerror(errno));
            return 0;
        }
    }

    if ( resp[iIn-1] == '\r' )
        resp[iIn-1] = '\0';
    else
        resp[iIn] = '\0';

    return iIn;
}


int getbaud( int fd ) 
{
    struct termios termAttr;
    int inputSpeed = -1;
    speed_t baudRate;
    tcgetattr( fd, &termAttr );
    // Get the input speed
    baudRate = cfgetispeed( &termAttr );
    switch ( baudRate )
    {
        case B0:      inputSpeed = 0; break;
        case B50:     inputSpeed = 50; break;
        case B110:    inputSpeed = 110; break;
        case B134:    inputSpeed = 134; break;
        case B150:    inputSpeed = 150; break;
        case B200:    inputSpeed = 200; break;
        case B300:    inputSpeed = 300; break;
        case B600:    inputSpeed = 600; break;
        case B1200:   inputSpeed = 1200; break;
        case B1800:   inputSpeed = 1800; break;
        case B2400:   inputSpeed = 2400; break;
        case B4800:   inputSpeed = 4800; break;
        case B9600:   inputSpeed = 9600; break;
        case B19200:  inputSpeed = 19200; break;
        case B38400:  inputSpeed = 38400; break;
        case B115200: inputSpeed = 115200; break;
        case B2000000: inputSpeed = 2000000; break; //added
    }
    return inputSpeed;
}


/* ser.c
    (C) 2004-5 Captain http://www.captain.at

    Sends 3 characters (ABC) via the serial port (/dev/ttyS0) and reads
    them back if they are returned from the PIC.

    Used for testing the PIC-MMC test-board
    http://www.captain.at/electronic-index.php

*/


int initport( int fd, speed_t baudRate ) 
{
    struct termios options;
    struct sigaction saio;  // Definition of Signal action

    // Install the signal handler before making the device asynchronous
    saio.sa_handler = DAQ_signal_handler_IO;
    saio.sa_flags = 0;
    saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
    sigaction( SIGIO, &saio, NULL );

    // Allow the process to receive SIGIO
    fcntl( fd, F_SETOWN, getpid() );
    // Make the file descriptor asynchronous (the manual page says only 
    // O_APPEND and O_NONBLOCK, will work with F_SETFL...)
    fcntl( fd, F_SETFL, FASYNC );
    //~ fcntl( fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY); //doesn't work; //fcntl(file, F_SETFL, 0);

    // Get the current options for the port...
    tcgetattr( fd, &options );
/*       
    // Set port settings for canonical input processing
    options.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    options.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
    //options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    options.c_oflag = 0;
    options.c_lflag = ICANON;
    //options.c_lflag = 0;
    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
*/   
    /* ADDED - else 'read' will not return, unless it sees LF '\n' !!!!
    * From: Unix Programming Frequently Asked Questions - 3. Terminal I/O - 
    * http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_4.html 
    */
    /* Disable canonical mode, and set buffer size to 1 byte */
    options.c_lflag &= (~ICANON);
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 1; 

    // Set the baud rates to...
    cfsetispeed( &options, baudRate );
    cfsetospeed( &options, baudRate );

    // Enable the receiver and set local mode...
    options.c_cflag |= ( CLOCAL | CREAD );
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;

    // Flush the input & output...
    tcflush( fd, TCIOFLUSH );

    // Set the new options for the port...
    tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &options );

    return 1;
}


/* 
    ripped from 
    http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/stty.c
*/

#define STREQ(a, b)     (strcmp((a), (b)) == 0)

struct speed_map
{
  const char *string;       /* ASCII representation. */
  speed_t speed;        /* Internal form. */
  unsigned long int value;  /* Numeric value. */
};

static struct speed_map const speeds[] =
{
  {"0", B0, 0},
  {"50", B50, 50},
  {"75", B75, 75},
  {"110", B110, 110},
  {"134", B134, 134},
  {"134.5", B134, 134},
  {"150", B150, 150},
  {"200", B200, 200},
  {"300", B300, 300},
  {"600", B600, 600},
  {"1200", B1200, 1200},
  {"1800", B1800, 1800},
  {"2400", B2400, 2400},
  {"4800", B4800, 4800},
  {"9600", B9600, 9600},
  {"19200", B19200, 19200},
  {"38400", B38400, 38400},
  {"exta", B19200, 19200},
  {"extb", B38400, 38400},
#ifdef B57600
  {"57600", B57600, 57600},
#endif
#ifdef B115200
  {"115200", B115200, 115200},
#endif
#ifdef B230400
  {"230400", B230400, 230400},
#endif
#ifdef B460800
  {"460800", B460800, 460800},
#endif
#ifdef B500000
  {"500000", B500000, 500000},
#endif
#ifdef B576000
  {"576000", B576000, 576000},
#endif
#ifdef B921600
  {"921600", B921600, 921600},
#endif
#ifdef B1000000
  {"1000000", B1000000, 1000000},
#endif
#ifdef B1152000
  {"1152000", B1152000, 1152000},
#endif
#ifdef B1500000
  {"1500000", B1500000, 1500000},
#endif
#ifdef B2000000
  {"2000000", B2000000, 2000000},
#endif
#ifdef B2500000
  {"2500000", B2500000, 2500000},
#endif
#ifdef B3000000
  {"3000000", B3000000, 3000000},
#endif
#ifdef B3500000
  {"3500000", B3500000, 3500000},
#endif
#ifdef B4000000
  {"4000000", B4000000, 4000000},
#endif
  {NULL, 0, 0}
};

static speed_t
string_to_baud (const char *arg)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; speeds[i].string != NULL; ++i)
    if (STREQ (arg, speeds[i].string))
      return speeds[i].speed;
  return (speed_t) -1;
}



/* http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Elapsed-Time.html
Subtract the `struct timeval' values X and Y,
storing the result in RESULT.
Return 1 if the difference is negative, otherwise 0.  */
int timeval_subtract (struct timeval *result, struct timeval *x, struct timeval *y)
{
    /* Perform the carry for the later subtraction by updating y. */
    if (x->tv_usec < y->tv_usec) {
     int nsec = (y->tv_usec - x->tv_usec) / 1000000 + 1;
     y->tv_usec -= 1000000 * nsec;
     y->tv_sec += nsec;
    }
    if (x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec > 1000000) {
     int nsec = (x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec) / 1000000;
     y->tv_usec += 1000000 * nsec;
     y->tv_sec -= nsec;
    }

    /* Compute the time remaining to wait.
      tv_usec is certainly positive. */
    result->tv_sec = x->tv_sec - y->tv_sec;
    result->tv_usec = x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec;

    /* Return 1 if result is negative. */
    return x->tv_sec < y->tv_sec;
}
```

Comment: Like in the original code I didn't see any manipulation with internal loopback via *TIOCM_LOOP* flag. Your measurement is not only about serial port, but more realistic case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144976/enabling-and-testing-local-loop-back-for-uart