# Enabling and testing local loop back for UART

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, uart

I'm trying to do UART internal loop back testing and come up with below changes

```
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <termios.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <sys/ioctl.h>
 #include <sys/mman.h>
 #include <sys/errno.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <unistd.h>


 #define CCSR_BASE  0xfe000000
 #define UART1_BASE 0x11c000
 #define UART1_LEN  0x1000

 static volatile unsigned long  *uartReg = MAP_FAILED;

/* Map in registers. */
static unsigned long  *initMapMem(int fd, unsigned long addr, unsigned long len)
{
     return (unsigned long *) mmap(0, len,
            PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,MAP_SHARED|MAP_LOCKED, fd, addr);
}

int uartInitialise(void)
{
    int fd;
    int i;

    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC) ;

    if (fd < 0)
       {
           fprintf(stderr,"This program needs root privileges.Try sudo /n");
           return -1;
       }

   uartReg  = initMapMem(fd, ((CCSR_BASE) + (UART1_BASE))  , UART1_LEN);

   /* In local loop back mode, data written to UTHR(8 bit) can be read from the 
      receiver buffer register(URBR 8 bit) of the same UART. */

 //    *(uartReg + 0x605 )  = 0x0;

       *(uartReg + (0x600)) = 0xf;

       printf("UART_REG : %#x\n", *(int *)(uartReg + (0x600)); /*Expecting 0xf to read here if loop back mode is set */

       close(fd);

  if (uartReg == MAP_FAILED)
     {
        fprintf(stderr,"Bad, mmap failed\n");
        return -1;
     }

    return 0;
}

 int main()
 {
    int pins;
    int f = open( "/dev/ttyS1", O_RDWR);

    if (f< 0)
    {
        printf("\nout");
        close(f);
     }   

    ioctl( f, TIOCMGET, &pins);
    ioctl( f, TIOCMSET, pins | TIOCM_LOOP);

    if (uartInitialise() < 0) return 1;

    sleep(5);

   ioctl( f, TIOCMGET, &pins);
   ioctl( f, TIOCMSET, pins & ~ TIOCM_LOOP);

 }
```

root@amit:~# ./loop_back

UART_REG : 0

But I'm not getting expected output ,can any one point me out what needs to be done to get the UART internal loop back testing?

Comment: You're going about it wrong; you should not be interfering with the device registers while the driver is also active.  Instead you should check if the serial port driver supports the TIOCM_LOOP ioctl() call, and then simply write() and read().

Comment: Ok, I checked that "ioctl( f, TIOCMSET, pins | TIOCM_LOOP)" returns from "http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L2725" ,is it mean that serial port driver doesn't support TIOCM_LOOP ,if so what should I do :(

Comment: **tty_io.c** is not a serial port driver; it's part of the tty or terminal layer.  Serial port drivers would be in **drivers/tty/serial/**.  Apparently you don't enable compiler warnings or ignore them, because your call `ioctl( f, TIOCMSET, pins | TIOCM_LOOP)` is incorrect.  The third argument for TIOCMSET ioctl() according to the Linux **man** page is `const int *argp`.

Comment: Ok but then  something I followed should be wrong ,"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059104/rs-232-pin-configuration-in-linux-pc" :)

Comment: My general rule is to trust the **man** page over someone's example.  Then I'd check the Linux source code.  Or perform a test: do a TIOCMGET and then the TIOCSGET.  Do another TIOCMGET to verify (and always check the return codes).

Comment: I just looked into DTS file of my machine "https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/powerpc/boot/dts/fsl/qoriq-duart-0.dtsi" and corresponding serial port driver should be "drivers/tty/serial/of_serial.c" and looks to me loop back test is disabled , is this driver support TIOCM_LOOP ioctl call,please confirm !!!

Comment: **of_serial.c** is a catch-all for several drivers, especially 8250/16xxx compatible UARTs, which should support loopback. Use `dmesg` to examine the boot log and  `cat /proc/tty/driver/serial` for more accurate serial port & driver info.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :). Also flow would be like application code  --> tty_io.c ---> serial port driver ---> 8250_core.c, right?