# Serial internal (not external) loopback test

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, embedded, driver

Have a RS422 port with no physical cable and trying to do an ***internal*** loop back test.

(According to the serial controller manufacturer, an external loopback requires a cable and an internal or local does not.)

The serial controller is setup for standard communication. Next, call the OS write() to the device, with 64 bytes.

Then, in a loop driven by `ioctl(device, FIONREAD, currentBytesRead);` attempt to immediately read it back.

It appears to read the first byte and returns 0 bytes after that.

Any idea why the rest of the data is not available to read....and finally is this a valid test?

Comment: How could you perform an internal loopback test without cross cables?  RS422 is full duplex...

Comment: Your test is not valid.  You have to install the loopback ***before*** the write operation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144976/enabling-and-testing-local-loop-back-for-uart

Comment: find two paperclips...

Comment: @lps: Cables are not needed for an internal (local) loopback.

Comment: @dwelch: see comment above.

Comment: Ok. Then you are testing uart ttl side, not the RS422

Comment: @lps: ttl side meaning the serial controller hardware or the code layer? This test is suppose to test everything right up to the physical signal....like the one in the link from sawdust.

Comment: for the physical signal you need metal outside, times two for rs422.  for an internal loopback you dont.  now it may be on the "edge" of the logic but it is still internal.  Unless your board has relays on it or something that you can flip for a physical loop back (which is still metal outside the uart)...

Comment: Problem is an internal loopback does not test the transceivers and the connectors. Is soldering a few wires (two actually) **that** complicated?

Comment: What serial controller are you using?  how are you setting up the loop back mode?