# Using uTOLED-20 with RaspBerryPI

Tags: c++, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, 4d

Recently I bought an uTOLED-G20 with the 4D Serial Adaptor. My current hardware connection is the following one (enclosed picture) 
My goal is to show the camera in the uTOLED screen. But before to achieve this I would like to send "some picture (.gif, .bmp, .jpg) to the display", or some "Hello world".

Well this task is going me crazy. I was reading http://elinux.org/Serial_port_programming and nothing appears in the uToled.

I want able to develop some software in python or C, c++ in my Linux (RaspberryPI) and show the data in the screen.

Please could you help me from where I can start?

I will really appreciate all your feedback. :-)

[image: My hardware configuration]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is connect the RX and TX on the RPi together to make sure you are sending and receiving characters on the RPi.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your answer. What do you mean connecting RX and TX together?

Comment: Unplug the connector to LCD display and use a jumper to connect the pins labelled RX and TX.

Answer (score 0):

In follow up to the loopback test, you can do this with a few tricks from the command line. Essentially you can **#echo "foo" > /dev/ttyAMA0** from one console, and **#tail -f** from another console. For more specific directions check out this older post: [Serial port loopback/duplex test, in Bash or C? (process substitution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701955/serial-port-loopback-duplex-test-in-bash-or-c-process-substitution)

Comment: Hello Alex nothing happened , nothing in the screen and no errors :-( some ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, didn't get a notification about your reply. One thing to note, is that Raspi uses that serial port as a tty console. In order to disable the console you have to edit /etc/inittab and comment out the bit that is latching on the the serial port. It looks like this:

T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
^add a # symbol infront of that line and reboot