# Write and then read to serial port in C

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, read-write

I have a USB to serial adapter attached to `/dev/ttyUSB0` which connects to a rotation stage. I can communicate to that rotation stage by simply sending ASCII commands over the  serial port. i.e. to request the current position of that rotation stage just:

1. in window 1: `echo -e "1tp\r" > /dev/ttyUSB`
2. in window 2: `cat /dev/ttyUSB`   which returns the current position: "1TP-0.00000"

Now I want to be able to do exactly this at a certain trigger inside a C program.

I've browsed this amazing  archive and found a few examples of how it can be done. For example

- [how to open, read, and write from serial port in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c)
- [Linux C Serial Port Reading/Writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108932/linux-c-serial-port-reading-writing)
- [Serial port loopback/duplex test, in Bash or C? (process substitution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701955/serial-port-loopback-duplex-test-in-bash-or-c-process-substitution)

So based on those, I wrote this very ugly code to simply try writing "1tp\r" to the serial port and then reading the returned value ( the rotation stage position) back.  Here is the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char line[1024];
  int chkin;
  int chkout;
  char input[1024];
  char msg[1024];
  char serport[24];

  // argv[1] - serial port

  sprintf(serport, "%s", argv[1]);

  int file= open(serport, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  printf("file descriptor: %d\n",file);

  if (file == 0)
    {
      sprintf(msg, "open_port: Unable to open %s.\n", serport);
      perror(msg);
    }
  else
    fcntl(file, F_SETFL, FNDELAY); //fcntl(file, F_SETFL, 0);

  while (1)
    {

      usleep (1000000);
      // printf("enter input data:\n");
      //scanf("%s",&input[0]);
      // printf("You entered %s\n",&input);

      //input= "1tp\r";
      chkin = write(file,"1tp\r",5);
      printf("chkin: %d\n",chkin);

      if (chkin<0)
    {
          printf("cannot write to port\n");
    }
      fcntl(file, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
      //chkin=read(file,line,sizeof line);
      usleep (100000);

      //while ((chkin=read(file,line,sizeof line))>=0)
      //printf("chkin: %d\n",chkin);
      chkout = read(file, line ,sizeof line);
      //{
       if (chkout<0)
     {
       printf("cannot read from port\n");
     }
       else
     {
       printf("bytes: %d, line=%s\n",chkout, line);
     }
       //}

      /*CODE TO EXIT THE LOOP GOES HERE*/
      if (input[0] == 'q') break;
    }

  close(file);
  return 0;
}
```

Well, it doesn't work. When I run it as: `./sertest /dev/ttyUSB0`, I just get the error `"cannot read from port"`. In reality, the problem seems to be that the `"1tp\r"` string does not seem to get written to the serial port. In addition, once I am done with this, the serial port settings seem to be all messed up because I can't communicate at all with the stage via simple terminal commands and need to reset the serial port using minicom.

I should also note that I know I can successfully read something from the serial port with the second part of that code because I have managed to send the `"1tp\r"` string with a terminal command and just read the output of the  stage with the relevant snippet of code in the example below.

So, I would appreciate some input on how to successfully write this simple string `"1tp\r"` ( or a similar one) to the serial port and alternate to reading the serial port.

I am not a programmer so I apologize in advance for the poor style of the piece of code here.

Comment: There are only 4 characters to write. The `\r` is a single character, even though it looks like two. Specifically `\r` is a carriage return, hex value 0x0D.

Comment: Also, the `echo` command may be adding a gratuitous line-feed char to the end of the message. If that's the case, the code should be sending `"1tp\r\n"`, which actually *is* 5 characters.

Comment: Call `perror` immediately after the `write` call to give you a more precise indication of what the error is.

Comment: Or use `errno`. Did you check that you have write permission?

Comment: right. I fixed the string to write to "1tp\r\n" and its size is correctly 5. What argument should be in perror though ?     I forgot to say I am doing this as root, so yes I have permissions to write to /dev/ttyUSB0 ( either in commandline or in the C code.

Comment: Don't use `perror()` try this `fprintf(stderr, "error(%d): %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));`. instead, you have to include `errno.h`

Comment: Your command line test writes to **/dev/ttyUSB** but your code test writes to **/dev/ttyUSB0**.  Maybe you ought to try your code with **/dev/ttyUSB**